# Azcopy tool key revoked on Linux and can't login

Tags: linux, azure, ubuntu, azcopy

Azcopy command line tool cannot log in on Ubuntu (or Linux-based systems) with an error of key revoked. I have tried to log in many times using the Azure pass code but in vain.

Answer (score 0):

The solution is in three steps as follows:

1. Install keyutils using command `sudo apt install keyutils`.
2. Open a new session using `keyctl session`.
3. Try to log in again using `azcopy login`.